# How to generate non-random UUID based on string in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As we have multi threaded environment in ruby so need to generate every time same UUID like 9f54c0ae-f9cf-46ba-985d-637e1dcc0e5d base on same input string JOB_userId_jobId like JOb_1_90.

Example:
`"JOb_1_96"=>"412ce9ff-fb47-4b8e-94c9-4bd37481cb4b", 
"JOb_1_97"=>"7232e1d6-422e-4d49-a47f-f4628e4ffd57",
"JOb_1_98"=>"de932dbd-76e4-4828-8bc1-cebd8254db61",
"JOb_1_99"=>"ce1e91a3-8d5d-47f8-9dc6-58790cbb98e9",`
....

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Can you make question title shorter, with only relevant details, such as _How to generate non-random UUID based on string in ruby?_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand, UUIDs should not be random, but based on input string. This is known as "version 3" and "version 5" UUIDs. These versions differ by hashing function used: MD5 vs SHA1. See [rfc4122, section 4.3](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

If you don't mind including Activesupport dependency to your project (it's quite large gem, but popular and included in Rails), then you can use its `uuid_v3` and `uuid_v5` [methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Digest/UUID.html).

```
require "active_support/core_ext/digest/uuid"
puts Digest::UUID.uuid_v3("ae279f4c-6327-47c6-b53c-05a3f10dd0c6", "bar")
puts Digest::UUID.uuid_v5("ae279f4c-6327-47c6-b53c-05a3f10dd0c6", "bar")
```

Output (note that it's the same on each run, unlike random UUIDs):

```
fab2e5c9-bf64-39d4-bc17-e72ccdb013aa
15c252d7-fd16-52de-aac2-223a58aa6ea9
```

Comment: Actually there's no need to make the namespace into a UUID and it seems contraproductive to do so! From the mentioned RFC: _The version 3 or 5 UUID is meant for generating UUIDs from "names" that are drawn from, and unique within, some "name space".  The concept of name and name space should be broadly construed, and not limited to textual names.  For example, some name spaces are the domain name system, URLs, ISO Object IDs (OIDs), X.500 Distinguished Names (DNs), and reserved words in a programming language._